# Currently I am learning react, trying to create react app, when I try to run "npx parcel index.html" I am getting following error

Tags: reactjs, bundler, web-frontend, web-deployment-project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ymyk.png)
I am getting this error please tell me where I goes wrong

when I try to run command: npx parcel index.html it says are you meant to say App.js if I put it like App.js it will ignore html file of my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is suggesting that your app.js file could not be located inside the ./src folder inside index.The folder is unavailable as seen in the image. Please change your import from ./src/App.js to ./App.js